# Stay logged in across multiple domains

Tags: php, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross Domain Single Selective Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261300/cross-domain-single-selective-sign-in)

I'm using php on multiple domains that belong to the same website,
I was wondering if it's possible to keep the users logged in on all domains, once they log in, in one of the domains.

How is that possible?

Comment: Have you searched for this yet?  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that I really like, I prefer a method that works in the backend without any need for cookie sharing or things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something really simple and it works, you have one server with a session that remembers the user, then using javascript you query that server to see if it knows the user, if it does then you authenticate the same user on the current domain, you pass around a secret key to identify what user to log in.

Answer (score 1):

Look into OpenID, like what this site uses. http://openid.net/

Also, some questions that dealt with this:
[Cross Domain Login - How to login a user automatically when transferred from one domain to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transferred-from-one/342498#342498)

[Cross Domain Single Selective Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261300/cross-domain-single-selective-sign-in)

Comment: OpenId does not help me because the users will have to be redirected on each domain separately to the openid provider, am I wrong in saing that?