# Setting a cookie for different domain extensions

Tags: php, cookies

I have a website that's running across multiple domain extensions.
  Now I wish for my user to log in on one website, and be able to be remembered/auto logged in on all of them

Currently I have

```
domain.nl
domain.net
domain.co.uk
domain.info
domain.org
domain.eu
```

My header file sets the current cookie

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'domain.net');
```

Which obviously only works for .net.

I already tried: (below code is foreach domain ext. not only .net)

```
if($domext == 'net'){   
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'domain.net');
}
```

$domext is the current domain extension you are on,
stripped from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

But this also isn't working, Not only not logging in automatically, but it isn't working at all. still only for the .net domain...

How can I set the same cookie across multiple domains?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent user session over several sites (single sign-on + single sign-off)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043111/transparent-user-session-over-several-sites-single-sign-on-single-sign-off)